# How to find the 2D area of a surface of a part in ROBLOX?

Tags: lua, 3d, geometry, 2d, roblox

So I'm trying to find the 2D area of a surface of a part in ROBLOX, no matter its rotation, by using Raycasting. So I know how to find the normal of the raycast, as well as the surface Enum, but from there I don't know how to find the 2D size of the surface, no matter its rotation. For example, if a part was size (100,1,100) rotated (0,0,0) and also a part was size (100,100,1) rotated (90,0,0) and the normal of both raycasts to both parts would be (0,1,0), then 2D area of first part would be (100,0,100) and 2D area of second part would also be (100,0,100).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the function in the camera called `WorldToViewportPoint` and `WorldToScreenPoint`, they convert `Vector3` positions to `Vector2` positions and can access the Z coordinate in the `Vector2` perspective.